# Setting keys in Azure Key Vault without PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

How to set secrets in Azure Key Vault, without using PowerShell. We are using Azure Key Vault to securely store out connection strings and some other application secrets. We are able to add secrets using PowerShell scripts, but I was wondering if there is another way to add keys in Azure KeyVault, preferably using APIs. We actually need to provide a management tool using which application admins can add/modify secrets in the key vault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now add keys and secrets via the Azure Portal without having to use PowerShell.

Answer (score 3):

This question is quite old thought I'd add a new angle for people coming across it)...

You can now also store secrets using ARM templates, you have been able to for a little while, but it's been largely very difficult to find documentation for (took me some time to find when I first worked it out!), but here is a handy example in the azure quickstart templates:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-key-vault-secret-create/azuredeploy.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "keyVaultName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Key Vault"
      }
    },
    "tenantId": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Tenant Id for the subscription and use assigned access to the vault. Available from the Get-AzureRMSubscription PowerShell cmdlet"
      }
    },
    "accessPolicies": {
      "type": "array",
      "defaultValue": "{}",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Access policies object {\"tenantId\":\"\",\"objectId\":\"\",\"permissions\":{\"keys\":[\"\"],\"secrets\":[\"\"]}}"
      }
    },
    "vaultSku": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Standard",
        "Premium"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "SKU for the vault"
      }
    },
    "enabledForDeployment": {
      "type": "bool",
      "defaultValue": false,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies if the vault is enabled for VM or Service Fabric deployment"
      }
    },
    "enabledForTemplateDeployment": {
      "type": "bool",
      "defaultValue": false,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies if the vault is enabled for ARM template deployment"
      }
    },
    "enableVaultForVolumeEncryption": {
      "type": "bool",
      "defaultValue": false,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies if the vault is enabled for volume encryption"
      }
    },
    "secretsObject": {
      "type": "secureObject",
      "defaultValue": "{}",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "all secrets {\"secretName\":\"\",\"secretValue\":\"\"} wrapped in a secure object"
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
      "name": "[parameters('keyVaultName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-01",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "KeyVault"
      },
      "properties": {
        "enabledForDeployment": "[parameters('enabledForDeployment')]",
        "enabledForTemplateDeployment": "[parameters('enabledForTemplateDeployment')]",
        "enabledForVolumeEncryption": "[parameters('enableVaultForVolumeEncryption')]",
        "tenantId": "[parameters('tenantId')]",
        "accessPolicies": "[parameters('accessPolicies')]",
        "sku": {
          "name": "[parameters('vaultSku')]",
          "family": "A"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('keyVaultName'), '/', parameters('secretsObject').secrets[copyIndex()].secretName)]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-01",
      "properties": {
        "value": "[parameters('secretsObject').secrets[copyIndex()].secretValue]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/', parameters('keyVaultName'))]"
      ],
      "copy": {
        "name": "secretsCopy",
        "count": "[length(parameters('secretsObject').secrets)]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Albeit this may not be suitable for a management tool, but you never know.

Comment: Agree with @Alex KeySmith. We have moved to ARM templates now as well.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft do provide a REST API for that. You can check it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn903630.aspx).

Below is a PowerShell Script that shows you how to create a key with that API.

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure Active Directory Connect\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll'

$tenantID = "<your tenant ID>"
$loginEndpoint = "https://login.windows.net/"

# the common redirect URI and client ID
$redirectURI = New-Object System.Uri ("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob")
$clientID = "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2"

$resource = "https://vault.azure.net"

$authString = $loginEndpoint + $tenantID

$authenticationContext = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext ($authString, $false)

$promptBehaviour = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PromptBehavior]::Auto

$userIdentifierType = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserIdentifierType]::RequiredDisplayableId

$userIdentifier = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserIdentifier ("<your Azure account>", $userIdentifierType)

$authenticationResult = $authenticationContext.AcquireToken($resource, $clientID, $redirectURI, $promptBehaviour, $userIdentifier); 

# construct authorization header for the REST API.
$authHeader = $authenticationResult.AccessTokenType + " " + $authenticationResult.AccessToken
$headers = @{"Authorization"=$authHeader; "Content-Type"="application/json"}

$key = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri "https://<your key vault>.vault.azure.net/keys/<key name>/create?api-version=2015-06-01" -Headers $headers -Body '{"kty": "RSA","attributes": {"enabled": true}}'
```

I don't know what programing language you are using, so I use PowerShell because it's easy to test. The script is translated from C# code, so it can be easily translated back to C#. If you don't like the prompt behaviour, you can use credential with secured String. For other programing language, you can use the corresponding ADAL. If the ADAL is not available for that programing language, you can use OAuth2.

Comment: Is there a SDK available for this?

Comment: Yes, there is a .NET SDK for Azure Key Vault. See [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt430941.aspx)